# In maxima, why the following can't find root?

Tags: maxima-software

Why the following equation can't find root? 
Solve $\sqrt{x^2-22x+134}-\sqrt{x^2-6x+54}=0$

```
(%i1)  solve(sqrt(x^2-22*x+134) -sqrt(x^2-6*x+54),x);                 
                        2                       2
(%o1)            [sqrt(x  - 22 x + 134) = sqrt(x  - 6 x + 54)]
```

By calculating by hand, it is simple.
My question is why can't find root?

Comment: What a bunch of irrelevant answers...

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Well the question is silly. Does it matter why Maxima simply returns $[\sqrt(x^2-22*x+134)=\sqrt(x^2-6*x+54)]$ as a result of the input solve(sqrt(x^2-22*x+134)-sqrt(x^2-6*x+54)=0,x) if the problem can be solved by hand or if, when the equation is written more sensibly when input into Maxima, solve works fine.

Comment: @smcc: Whether or not this is a bad question is irrelevant. And sure, it might be off-topic altogether, or just missing some context. But I don't remember programming compilers that automatically write filesystem drivers and operating systems when I was trying to learn how to program. I do remember writing a lot of silly examples. Can you tell, in advance, if this is an attempt to understand Maxima, or just solve one equation? I sure as hell can't. But I can say that when someone tells you that their fish is dead, the right answer is not "have you looked under the fridge?"

Comment: That being said, if the question had been "Why do solve(sqrt(x^2-22*x+134)-sqrt(x^2-6*x+54)=0,x) and solve((x^2-22*x+134)-(x^2-6*x+54)=0,x) return different output in Maxima?" I think it would have been a good question if OP's intention is to learn about the solve function in Maxima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Maxima manual entry for the function *solve*

"Solves the algebraic equation $\text{expr}$ for the variable $x$ and returns a list of solution equations in $x$... $\text{expr}$ may be a rational expression, and may contain trigonometric functions, exponentials, etc."

Given the "etc", the manual is not very clear about which expressions *solve* works well on. But from experimentation, *solve* does not handle unsimplified expressions involving fractional exponents or logarithms very well.

For example Maxima returns an implicit solution (the equation itself) when attempting to use *solve* (with out any prior simplification) on any equation of the form

$$(x+1)^{n}=(2x)^{n},\quad \text{ where $n\in(0,1)$}$$
or
$$\quad \ln(2x)=\ln(1+x).$$

If instead we help Maxima by simplifying first to get $x+1=2x$, then *solve* has no trouble returning the explicit solution.

Answer (score 1):

your equation is $$\sqrt{(x^2-22x+134)}=\sqrt{(x^2-6x+54)}$$ squaring and simplifying we get 
$$-22x+134=-6x+54$$
and we get $$80=16x$$ or $$x=5$$
why maxima can not find the solution i dont know, i don't know the code

---

In this case we have to assist Maxima. 
We use the same idea, to calculate the solution. More complex cases can be handled like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3512647/11206).

```
(%i1) eq:sqrt(x^2-22*x+134)-sqrt(x^2-6*x+54)
                        2                       2
(%o1)             sqrt(x  - 22 x + 134) - sqrt(x  - 6 x + 54)
(%i2) s:solve(eq,x)
                        2                       2
(%o2)            [sqrt(x  - 22 x + 134) = sqrt(x  - 6 x + 54)]
(%i3) s:s^2
                         2                 2
(%o3)                  [x  - 22 x + 134 = x  - 6 x + 54]
(%i4) solve(s,x)
(%o4)                               [x = 5]
```

Or you can the function `to_poly_solve`

```
(%i2) load(to_poly_solve)$
(%i3) to_poly_solve(sqrt(x^2-22*x+134) -sqrt(x^2-6*x+54),x);
(%o3)                           %union([x = 5])
```

Comment: Hi @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have hijacked your answer to add a Maxima solution. The question is closed so no new answer can be added. I hope this is ok, otherwise feel free to roll back my edit.